# Qt4 / C++ / CMake - no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, cmake, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator 3.1.2/Qt4.8.6 and CMake3.0.0. Note that I'm using SceniX API if you're concerned about my CMakeLists.txt but that doesn't affect this. However, when compiling a UI generated by Qt Creator I get the following error:

```
D:\Projects\C Projects\MyProjectName\ui\masterui.cpp:6: error: C2512: 'Ui::MasterUI' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

However, the default constructor IS available. These are default files generated by Qt Creator and setup for use in CMake. They might be slightly modified while experimenting but they have never worked.

I will share my masterui.h / masterui.cpp / CMakeLists.txt in that order.

**masterui.h**

```
#ifndef MASTERUI_H
#define MASTERUI_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class MasterUI;
}

class MasterUI : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MasterUI(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MasterUI();

private:
    Ui::MasterUI *ui;
};

#endif // MASTERUI_H
```

**masterui.cpp**

```
#include "masterui.h"
#include "ui_masterui.h"

MasterUI::MasterUI(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MasterUI)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MasterUI::~MasterUI()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(MyProjectName)

file(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{SCENIXHOME} SCENIX_HOME)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${SCENIX_HOME}/CMake")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../exe/MyProjectName_exe")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../exe/MyProjectName_exe")

file(GLOB sources
        "src/*.cpp")

file(GLOB headers
        "inc/*.h")

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(SceniX REQUIRED)
find_package(NVQt4 QUIET)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)

set( QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE )
include( ${QT_USE_FILE} )

SCENIX_SET_BINARY_FOLDERS()

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QTResources)

QT4_WRAP_UI(UIsrc "ui/masterui.ui")
QT4_WRAP_CPP(MOCsrc "ui/masterui.h")
ADD_EXECUTABLE(UIexe "src/main.cpp" "ui/masterui.cpp" ${MOCsrc} ${UIsrc})
file( GLOB UICsources
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*.h")
set( UIC_SOURCES "${UICsources}")

set( SCENIX_COMMON_BASE "${SCENIX_HOME}/samples/common" )

file( GLOB uisources
      "${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/src/ui/*.cpp" )

set( UI_SOURCES "${uisources}" )

set( MyProjectName_SOURCES
  ${sources}
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/src/SimpleScene.cpp
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/src/MeshGenerator.cpp
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/src/SceneFunctions.cpp
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/src/SceniXWidget.cpp
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/Qt4/src/SceniXQGLContext.cpp
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/Qt4/src/SceniXQGLWidget.cpp
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/Qt4/src/SceniXQGLSceneRendererWidget.cpp
  ${UI_SOURCES}
  ${UIC_SOURCES}
  ${QTResources}
  ${UICsources}
)

set ( MyProjectName_HEADERS
  ${headers}
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/inc/SimpleScene.h
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/inc/MeshGenerator.h
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/inc/SceneFunctions.h
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/inc/SceniXWidget.h
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/Qt4/inc/SceniXQGLContext.h
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/Qt4/inc/SceniXQGLWidget.h
  ${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/Qt4/inc/SceniXQGLSceneRendererWidget.h
)

include_directories( ${SCENIX_INCLUDES} )
include_directories( ${SCENIXRT_INCLUDES} )
include_directories( "." )
include_directories( "inc" )
include_directories( "${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/inc" )
include_directories( "${SCENIX_COMMON_BASE}/Qt4/inc" )
include_directories( "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}" )

add_executable( MyProjectName
  ${MyProjectName_SOURCES}
  ${MyProjectName_HEADERS}
)

target_link_libraries( MyProjectName
  ${QT_LIBRARIES}
  ${SCENIX_LIBS}
  ${SCENIXRT_LIBS}
  ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}
  ${QT_QTMAIN_LIBRARY}
)


if(TARGET SceniX)
  add_dependencies( MyProjectName SceniX SceniXRT )
  add_perforce_to_target( MyProjectName )
endif()

set_target_properties( MyProjectName PROPERTIES FOLDER "Samples")
```

---

**ui_masterui.h**

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'masterui.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 4.8.6
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_MASTERUI_H
#define UI_MASTERUI_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtGui/QHeaderView>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_masterWidget
{
public:

    void setupUi(QWidget *masterWidget)
    {
        if (masterWidget->objectName().isEmpty())
            masterWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("masterWidget"));
        masterWidget->resize(640, 360);
        masterWidget->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);"));

        retranslateUi(masterWidget);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(masterWidget);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QWidget *masterWidget)
    {
        masterWidget->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("masterWidget", "Form", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class masterWidget: public Ui_masterWidget {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MASTERUI_H
```

Comment: What makes you think that "the default constructor IS available"?  The only constructor defined for `Ui::MasterUI` takes a parameter.

Comment: Without the parameter the result is the same. It works with QMake.

Comment: Does removing the "explicit" keyword from the constructor help?

Comment: No difference at all unfortunately.

Comment: The default constructor is referring to the class in "ui_MasterUI.h", what's the contents of the file, and is there a default contructor there?

Comment: I have added it to the bottom of the original post. This file is automatically generated by uic based on the .ui file. As far as I know there's nothing I can do about the contents of that file other than the UI elements present. It's the same regardless of using qmake or cmake, and it works with qmake and not cmake. It is likely to be associated with the CMakeLists.txt file

Comment: @nix: a constructor with default arguments provided for every parameter is a default constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no Ui::MasterUI class in "ui_MasterUI.h", the closest one is Ui::masterWidget, hence you get the error.

I am guessing that you renamed MasterUI to masterWidget in Qt Designer, or by editing MasterUI.ui. This will cause Qt to generate "ui_MasterUI.h" with a Ui::masterWidget class, not Ui::MasterUI. The solution is to rename masterWidget back to MasterUI, or change masterui.cpp and masterui.h to refer to Ui::masterWidget instead of Ui::MasterUI.

Are you sure the same source files are still compilable with qmake?

Comment: Turns out changing the object name of the root widget changes the entire class name in the ui_masterui.h file. Thanks for that. Unfortunately now I have to solve 71 unresolved externals and no clue where to begin but I suppose that's a different thing.